# How to align the elements in TableRow

Tags: android

I am trying to Display data received from the server in tabs format as shown below

[image]

The below code is in a **for loop**

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                row.setLayoutParams(lp);
               TextView textview1 = new TextView(this);
                textview1.setText(received.getData(i+1,1));
                TextView textview2 = new TextView(this);
                textview2.setText(received.getData(i+1,2));
                TextView textview3 = new TextView(this);
                textview3.setText(received.getData(i+1,3));
                TextView textview4 = new TextView(this);
            row.addView(textview1);
            row.addView(textview2);
            row.addView(textview3);
            row.addView(textview4);
            tabLayout.addView(row,i);
```

I am trying to add data items like this.  i have to make the alignment of the data items similar. The width of each item should be **89dp**. I am not sure how to achieve this. Can anyone help me with the code to include the **89dp** width in each `TextViews`.

And also in addition how can I set color to single `TextView`?
I tried the following code but it didnt set any color to that field.

```
textview4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call

```
textview4.setWidth(int here);
```

And for setting the text color are you sure R.color.colorPrimary is the correct color?

try:

```
textview4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

this will make it red for testing to see if it changes.

Comment: thanks for your help. width is working but color is not working

Comment: i only need to change the text of one textview. i have not defined any textview in xml so i think ill need to do it in code

Comment: @sagar.acharya for testing purposes try changing it to `textview4.setTextColor(Color.RED);`

Comment: @sagar.acharya Mark this answer as correct if it fixed your problems. So other SO users have the same issue they will know what fixes it

Comment: text color is still not working. background colour works though. sorry for the late reply .